# How do I change the Display Name of an Exchange/Outlook.com Account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, outlook.com

I found a way to synchronize my windows contacts and calendar with Outlook by configuring outlook.com via Exchange in Outlook.

However, in Outlook in the folder view, the name of my account is just a GUID prefixed by `outlook_`:

[image: Outlook Folder view]

Is it somehow possible to change the name, or use at least my real email adress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue usually occur for users with multiple account aliases, and a non Microsoft domain alias is used as the primary alias. Microsoft is aware of this issue and the Outlook Team is doing work that will enable some supported use of aliases in the near future.

If above applies to your situation, try this workaround:

1. Go to https://account.live.com/names/Manage and sign in to your Outlook.com account.
2. Set your Outlook.com email as the primary alias.
3. In Outlook for Windows, remove and re-add the account. See the steps in this article: [Add your Outlook.com account in Outlook for Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-your-outlook-com-account-in-outlook-for-windows-642c1902-bdd9-4dc3-abe7-76d60b148b23)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the display name of any Outlook mailbox by changing its **PR_DISPLAY_NAME** property. To do this, you can write a VBA macro or use one of the free tools. For example, Microsoft's [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/releases/latest) or [Set Outlook Store Property](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookStoragePropertiesSet) developed by my company. In the second tool, just select your mailbox by clicking the Configure... button and specify PR_DISPLAY_NAME as a Property name and desired display name as a Value to set.